# django transaction doesn't works

Tags: python, django, transactions

i'm using django(1.10) and django-restframework(3.4.6).

i'm trying to adapt transaction on my code, but it not works!

code is below:

```
class Home(View):
def get(self, request):
    with transaction.atomic():
        Episode.objects.filter(id=1).update(volume=12)
        if True:
            raise Exception('test exception')
        Episode.objects.filter(id=2).update(volume=13)

    return render(request, 'home/home.html')
```

i already tried with decorator (@transaction.atomic), but it doesn't works too!

and i tried with ATOMIC_REQUESTS = True in setting, but but it doesn't works too...

i can't understand why this code not works... what am i missing?

db setting here:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'dragon',
    'USER': ...,
    'PASSWORD': ...,
    'HOST': ...,
    'PORT': '3306',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'sql_mode': 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
    }
    ...
```

mysql db engine is InnoDB.

mysql tx_isolation: REPEATABLE-READ

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "it doesn't work"? What happens, and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: i've expected both episodes rollback and not changed. but episode1's volume has changed and committed.